# Spring MVC/Hibernate: Autowired service in controller is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to `@Autowire` a `@Service` in a `@Controller`. This results in a runtime `NullPointerException` (where I attempt to make use of the `@Service`). For some reason Spring isn't injecting the dependency and I'm yet to figure it out. It doesn't seem to be because of the two primary causes (manual instanstiation or lack of annotations).

ReviewController:

```
package group9.movie_reviews.controller;

import group9.movie_reviews.service.impl.ReviewService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/review")
@SessionAttributes("review")
public class ReviewController {

    @Resource
    private ReviewService reviewService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String wtf(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("a", reviewService.getReviews()); // NullPointerException here
        return "index";
    }

}
```

ReviewService:

```
package group9.movie_reviews.service;

import group9.movie_reviews.model.ReviewEntity;

public interface ReviewService {

    Iterable<ReviewEntity> getReviews();

    void addReview(String movieName);

}
```

ReviewServiceImpl:

```
package group9.movie_reviews.service.impl;

import group9.movie_reviews.model.ReviewEntity;
import group9.movie_reviews.repository.ReviewRepository;
import group9.movie_reviews.service.ReviewService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Service
public class ReviewServiceImpl implements ReviewService {

    @Resource
    private ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    @Override
    public Iterable<ReviewEntity> getReviews() {
        return reviewRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addReview(String movieName) {
        ReviewEntity r = new ReviewEntity();
        r.setMovieName(movieName);
        reviewRepository.save(r);
    }

}
```

ReviewRepository:

```
package group9.movie_reviews.repository;

import group9.movie_reviews.model.ReviewEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ReviewRepository extends JpaRepository<ReviewEntity, Integer> {
    ReviewEntity findByMovieName(String movieName);
}
```

Stacktrace/error:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    group9.movie_reviews.controller.ReviewController.wtf(ReviewController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Config Files:

WebConfig:

```
package group9.movie_reviews.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"group9.movie_reviews"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"group9.movie_reviews.repository"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

WebInit:

```
package group9.movie_reviews.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Configuration
public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/", "/review"};
    }

}
```

Redeploy exception/stacktrace:

```
[2018-11-22 02:53:37,857] Artifact movie_reviews:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22-Nov-2018 02:53:37.878 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [    Thu Nov 22 02:35:08 GMT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
22-Nov-2018 02:53:37.878 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.doClose Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Nov 22 02:35:08 GMT     2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:997)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.destroy(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stopInternal(StandardWrapper.java:1729)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5573)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.unmanageApp(HostConfig.java:1755)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.removeContext(MBeanFactory.java:792)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor238.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

22-Nov-2018 02:53:37.880 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Nov 22 02:35:08 GMT 2018];     root of context hierarchy
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.095 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of     JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.197 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.305 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Nov 22 02:53:40     GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.400 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class     group9.movie_reviews.config.RootConfig]
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.709 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 512 ms
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.713 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.719 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet':     startup date [Thu Nov 22 02:53:40 GMT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
22-Nov-2018 02:53:40.722 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(83)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class     group9.movie_reviews.config.WebConfig]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[2018-11-22 02:53:41,443] Artifact movie_reviews:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-11-22 02:53:41,443] Artifact movie_reviews:war exploded: Deploy took 3,586 milliseconds
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group9</groupId>
    <artifactId>movie_reviews</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>movie_reviews</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <servlet-version>3.1.0</servlet-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Let's see a stacktrace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's a NullPointerException :/ added anyway

Comment: Making sure you're reading it right. Do you have a `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean registered to process the `@Resource` annotation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know what that is so I guess not. I have tried this with `@Autowired` annotations also, but intelliJ complains less with `@Resource` annotations. Still get the same error with `@Autowired`

Comment: could you also attach the spring.config that you are using, xml or class config? Also as mentioned above , resource is used to define endpoints and not just services

Comment: @AntJavaDev Have done - FYI RootConfig (referenced in WebInit) is currently an empty class

Comment: hmm , the config looks ok , are u sure that the `NullPointerException` occurs due to null service or due to null `ModelMap` ? ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev If I replace the call to the service with say a static string then everything works just fine. I even did a sanity check to pass a certain string `if (reviewService == null)`

Comment: yeap thats correct , wanted to verify that you are not using any custom interceptors / filters. And that the only error you are getting, right ? no other error during start up ? it should complain already if the bean couldn't be injected

Comment: @AntJavaDev Could it be injected as null if there is a problem with the hibernate config/connection to the DB? just a thought

Comment: `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` will be registered automatically if you have the `javax.annotation` library on your classpath at runtime. I don't know about IntelliJ complaints, but it should work fine with `@Autowired` as well (which doesn't need an additional dependency).

Comment: @AntJavaDev I do get an exception when I redeploy to Tomcat, but I that happens regardless of the autowiring etc. and doesn't seem to be related. I'll add it to the end of the post

Comment: yeap thats just a warning , also you are not deploying your app in different packages , its just a war / jar , correct?

Comment: @AntJavaDev I'm just deploying it as a single exploded war (followed some tutorial). The only artifact is the exploded war

Comment: exploded :P :P :P  ,  so the service / controller / repository packages are all in the same 'war' project ? ? Also as suggester by @SotiriosDelimanolis , have you tried replacing you `@Resource` with `@Autowired` in both controller and service classes ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev sorry, I'm new to this, not sure how I should call it. Yes, the 'war' is the entire project. Yes, I did try replacing them, the error was exactly the same

Comment: ye thats correct , exploded archive , i m just saying :P let me try replicate the same

Comment: ok i tried the same and indeed it worked as expected. What does not make sense in the examples you have posted , inside the controller class , you are trying to autowire the `ReviewService` but you are importing the `ReviewServiceImpl` , is that just a typo ? Could you try autowire the `ReviewServiceImpl` explicitly

Comment: @AntJavaDev That was a typo when I made the post. I was originally trying to `@Autowire` ReviewService but I tried autowiring ReviewServiceImpl just before making the post. I forgot to change the import in the post. I've tried both and both produce the same NullPointerException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184107/discussion-between-user3278983-and-antjavadev).

Comment: I think you didn't include the package where your service is located in your `@ComponentScan`